# Day of Lailat-al Qadr

Tags: laylat-al-qadr

Almost every Muslim child knows that `Lailatul Qadr` is 27th of `Ramadan`. But when they grow up, some of them try to know more and conclude that `Lailatul Qadr` can take place at any day of Ramadan.

Growing some more, I listened that `Lailatul Qadr` can take place at any day of the year, not only in `Ramadan`. What is the true fact? Can `Lailatul Qadr` take place without `Ramadan`? Please describe with evidence. Jajakallah.

Answer (score 3):

We don't actually know which night it is, 27 is just a popular view and not backed by any reliable Hadith. There's one from Muawiya b. Abi Sufyan that mentions the Prophet stated the 27th, however, it's inauthentic.  And it's possible the Qadr can be in other nights.

The Prophet said to seek Layl al-Qadr on the odd nights of the last 10 nights.  And this is backed by numerous authentic reports from different companions collected in the books of Sahih.

So seeking the night is far stronger and recommended than knowing when it is.

Comment: Should it be seek in Ramadan or the whole year? My main point of view was that. Jajakallah.

Comment: Last ten odd nights in Ramadan.  Nights of 21, 23, 25, 27... please remember to keep us all in your duas for good

Answer (score -3):

i think, it is not said in quran that it is in ramadan, only said in hadithes, and hadithes may be false, so that hadithes can be false until you thoroughly check their chain of narrators etc. also idea of laylatul-qadr as a real earth-rotation night looks quite dubious by point of view of sciense, physics